# How to resolve file not found when loading interop dll with .net core 3.0?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, com

I'm trying to port some code from .net frame 4.7.1 to .net core 3.0.

The problem is that we have a C++ COM assembly that we use a manifest to reference in out .net project.

I've added the project to the new solution and added the reference. An interop dll was created, but when I try to run the code I get an exception

```
{"Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Interop.MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"}
```

The file is in the output folder for the project. The actual com assembly wasn't, but even copying it in doesn't work.

Comment: COM is windows specific, i have doubt regarding its compatibility with .Net core, which needs to work with Linux and Mac too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43795656/17034

Comment: That doesn't work because the .net core version of MSBuild can't build the project. 
    error : MSB4803: The task "ResolveComReference" is not supported on the .NET Core version of MSBuild.

Answer (score 2):

The answer turns out to be that adding a reference in visual studio doesn't work for .net core apps.

The solution is to create a .net framework app, add the reference, then copy the comreference sections of the csproj into your .net core project.

Answer (score 0):

EmbedInteropTypes!!! took me forever to find this...!!

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">
  <HintPath>Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll</HintPath>
  <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
</Reference>
```